# How to extract sub-folder path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have about 100 folders and in each folder files that should be read and analyzed.

I can read the files from their subfolders, but I want to start processing at e.g. the 10th folder until the end. And I need the exact folder path.

How can I do this?

To clarify my question, I extracted a sample from my code:

```
rootDir = 'D:/PhD/result/Pyradiomic_input/'
for (path, subdirs, files) in os.walk(rootDir):        
    sizefile=len(path)
    if "TCGA-" in path :
        print(path)
```

The output is:

```
D:/PhD/result/Pyradiomic_input/TCGA-02-0006
D:/PhD/result/Pyradiomic_input/TCGA-02-0009
D:/PhD/result/Pyradiomic_input/TCGA-02-0011
D:/PhD/result/Pyradiomic_input/TCGA-02-0027
D:/PhD/result/Pyradiomic_input/TCGA-02-0046
D:/PhD/result/Pyradiomic_input/TCGA-02-0069
```

Now my question is how can I start working from e.g. `D:/PhD/result/Pyradiomic_input/TCGA-02-0046` until the end, instead of starting from the top? I tried some ideas but they did not work.

Comment: you can save the names of the files that you need to a list or any other iteratable object and then loop though it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a flag to capture when you hit a specific directory

```
rootDir = 'D:/PhD/result/Pyradiomic_input/'
first_folder = 'TCGA-02-0046'

process = False
for (path, subdirs, files) in os.walk(rootDir):        
    sizefile=len(path)
    if "TCGA-" in path :
        print(path)

        if first_folder in path:
            process = True

        if process:
            #process folder
```

If you want a specific folder to indicate the script should stop processing

```
rootDir = 'D:/PhD/result/Pyradiomic_input/'
first_folder = 'TCGA-02-0046'
last_folder = 'TCGA-02-0099'

process = False
for (path, subdirs, files) in os.walk(rootDir):        
    sizefile=len(path)
    if "TCGA-" in path :
        print(path)

        if first_folder in path:
            process = True

        if last_folder in path:
            break

        if process:
            #process folder
```

You can also set a list of directories that you want to process

```
rootDir = 'D:/PhD/result/Pyradiomic_input/'
process_dirs = ['TCGA-02-0046', ...]

process = False
for (path, subdirs, files) in os.walk(rootDir):        
    sizefile=len(path)
    if "TCGA-" in path :
        print(path)

        if any(d in path for d in process_dirs):
            #process folder
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply skip the values you aren't interested in. Here a bit simplified:

```
counter = 0

# mocking the file operations
for path in ["/dir-1", "/dir-2", "/dir-3", "/dir-4", "/dir-5"]:
  # skip the first two paths
  if counter < 2:
    counter += 1
    continue

  # do something    
  print(path)
```

Alternatively you could collect the paths first, like this:

```
paths = []

# mocking the file operations
for path in ["/dir-1", "/dir-2", "/dir-3", "/dir-4", "/dir-5"]:
  # collect paths in array
  paths.append(path)

# skip the first two elements
paths = paths[2:]

for path in paths:
  # do something
  print(path)
```

The second version can become a bit shorter if you use generator expressions, but I favor readability.